# SELECT FROM @itab causes syntax error. Why?

Tags: abap, opensql

I try to use `SELECT FROM @itab` like explained [here in SAP docs](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/de-DE/abapselect_itab.htm).

I have never used this feature, but think this is great. You can query a internal data structure which just exists in the RAM of the interpreter like it would be a real table in the database. I am impressed.

Here is the ABAP code:

```
data: lt_get_auth_values TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF US335.

CALL FUNCTION 'GET_AUTH_VALUES'
     EXPORTING
            OBJECT1 = 'Z:FOO'
            USER    = sy-uname
     TABLES
            VALUES  = lt_get_auth_values.

SELECT highval from @lt_get_auth_values as mytab WHERE field = 'WERKS' 
        INTO TABLE @DATA(static_perm_filter_fields).
```

I can't active the function because "from @lt_get_auth_values" is a syntax error according to my system.

What's wrong with this line?

SAP Version: 740 (sorry, it first I thought it was 752)

Comment: You are missing spaces on both side of the `=` sign. Correct and check again.

Comment: I would check this first: "Mit der Methode USE_FEATURES der Klasse CL_ABAP_DBFEATURES kann in einem ABAP-Programm festgestellt werden, ob das aktuelle Datenbanksystem oder ein Datenbanksystem, auf das über eine Sekundärverbindung zugegriffen wird, den Zugriff auf interne Tabellen unterstützt. Hierzu muss die Konstante ITABS_IN_FROM_CLAUSE dieser Klasse in einer internen Tabelle an die Methode übergeben werden." This is from the docu you provided by link, there is also a sample code to this.

Comment: Appeared in 7.52 so it should work (if you correct the error mentioned by András). On my 7.52 system it works but **you must indicate a table alias**. There's an example in the ABAP doc. [Doc in **English**](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapselect_itab.htm)

Comment: @SandraRossi I am sorry. This is a different system, and there is only 740, not version 752. I guess this is the reason.

Comment: if you use a literal (like 'highval') in a SELECT, you need to give it an alias (`'highval' AS highval`)

Comment: @guettli no doubt that 7.40 doesn't support this [new 7.52 Open SQL feature (#1)](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abennews-752-open_sql.htm)! ;-)

Comment: @SandraRossi, turn this intow an answer, so others can find it easier

Comment: @András ok ; feel free to import your own answers in my answer opened to community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SELECT ... FROM @itab](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abapselect_itab.htm) appeared in [7.52](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abennews-752-open_sql.htm) so it should work.

On my 7.52 system it works but **you must indicate a table alias**. There's an example in the ABAP documentation (cf first link above).

Comment: @guettli the last functional error is that you store literally `highval` into all lines of `static_perm_filter_fields`, instead of the value from component `highval`of `lt_get_auth_values` ; to correct it, you should use `SELECT highval FROM ...` instead of `SELECT 'highval' FROM ...`