# How to use SELECT on an internal table?

Tags: select, abap, opensql

I have an internal table that I want to filter further and further based on whether data is present. I have tried the following, but unfortunately I cannot apply a **SELECT** an internal table.

How can I solve this problem?

```
"Here I'm getting the hole database into my internal table 
SELECT * FROM TABLE
  INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE @itab.

"This should be my first filter if iv_name is not initial
IF iv_name IS NOT INITIAL.
  SELECT * FROM itab
    WHERE NAME = @iv_name
    INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE @itab. 
ENDIF.

"This should be my second filter if iv_age is not initial
IF iv_age IS NOT INITIAL.
  SELECT * FROM itab
    WHERE AGE = @iv_age
    INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE @itab. 
ENDIF.
```

Comment: What version are you on? SELECT from internal table [works since 7.52](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapselect_itab.htm).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SELECT FROM @itab causes syntax error. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53611910/select-from-itab-causes-syntax-error-why)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways in ABAP to achieve your goal.
You can use the DELETE keyword to filter the data in an internal table:

```
IF iv_name IS NOT INITIAL    
  DELETE itab WHERE name NE iv_name.
ENDIF.
```

Another possibility is to use the FILTER keyword, but the prerequisite is, that the internal table is TYPE SORTED or HASHED:

```
itab = FILTER #( itab WHERE name = iv_name ).
```